# Python Space Key Press Event not captured when using QLineEdit()

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to detect different keypress events while I write into a QLineEdit() widget. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.w = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.w, 0, 0)
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:
            print("Tab Key pressed")
            
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            print("Space Key pressed")
            
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Return Key pressed")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The return key and the tab key are both successfully captured, but the space bar is not captured. How can I fix this?

This is what I get

[image]

### Edit

What I would like to achieve:

If I type this:

[image]

it should print:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment so I am writing this. You are not capturing `KeyPressEvent` for `QLineEdit`. Instead, you are only capturing for `QWidget`. If you want to capture keyPress for `QLineEdit` you must inherit `QLineEdit`.

Now since `QLineEdit` in your widget has focus naturally all the keypress will be captured only by QLineEdit. You check this by adding focus to your widget using `self.setFocus()`. Then your widget will be able to capture all key events.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.w = LineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.w, 0, 0)


class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
        super(LineEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
            print("Tab Key pressed")

        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:
            print("Space Key pressed")

        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Return Key pressed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, another way might be to connect a textChanged signal to a slot.

eg:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.w.textChanged.connect(self.keyPress)
        layout.addWidget(self.w, 0, 0)

    def keyPress(self, key):
        if key[-1] == " ":
            print("Space Key pressed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Window()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This seems to capture the Space Key, but I cannot type anything anymore. I would like to both be able to type a sentence and have the space key captured. 

...and if I just add self.setFocus() to my _init_ in my class, it will capture the space key, but as soon as I start typing something, it stops capturing.

Comment: @henry You need to call the parent method. `super(Window, self).keyPressEvent(event)`

Comment: I am not sure, that I understand correctly how you would implement it. Would you mind changing your code to reflect your suggestion? That would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great answer! What exactly does super(Window, self).keyPressEvent(event) change?

Comment: @henry I have added another answer that might be what you are looking for. As for super it just calls the parent method implementation of the `KeyPressEvent`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! I didn't know about "textChanged".  Just to linger a bit more on the KeyPressEvent. Why do you need to call the parent method in order to capture the space key? I am sorry, I don't quite understand that part.

Comment: @henry [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) Almost all widgets are subclass of QWidget. QLineEdit will have its own implementation of `KeyPressEvent`  so it's important to call it.

Comment: @henry that's not a "parent method", that's the base class implementation (what the method does by default for that class, which is to react to key events and showing in the line edit, in this case). Do some research on classes, instances, and how their methods work. Also do some studying on all the documentation about QWidget, and remember that if you use a class you *must* do research on its docs (and on all docs of all classes it inherits from).